# Adding a second level to my Game

Tags: java, javafx, constructor

Changed up my code to this. Trying to instantiate a new Level 1 from my Game class. However nothing now shows when i run the application.

```
public class Game extends Application {

    Pane backgroundPane;
    Pane playfieldLayer;
    Pane scoreLayer;

    Level2 level2;

     Image playerImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("warehouse.png").toExternalForm());
     Image wallImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("Wall.png").toExternalForm());
     Image foodImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("food.png").toExternalForm());
     Image diamondImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("Chef.png").toExternalForm());

     Player player;
     Wall wall;

     List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Diamonds> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean collision;
     boolean wallCollision;
     boolean foodWallCollision;
     boolean won = false;

     GridPane gameGrid;
     static Scene scene;
     Stage theStage;

     Input input;




    @Override

    public void start(Stage theStage) {


        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Scene menuView = new Scene(menu, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH);

        theStage.setScene(menuView);
        // theStage.setResizable(false);

        theStage.show();

        Menu.start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                runGame(theStage);

            }
        });

    }

    public void runGame(Stage theStage) {

        // Input input = new Input(scene);

        Group root = new Group();

        GridPane gameGrid = new GamePane(14, 14);
        gameGrid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-grid-lines-visible:true");
        backgroundPane = new Pane();
        backgroundPane.setId("root");
        playfieldLayer = new Pane();
        scoreLayer = new Pane();

        playfieldLayer.getChildren().add(gameGrid);
        root.getChildren().add(backgroundPane);
        root.getChildren().add(playfieldLayer);

        // scene = new Scene(root, (columnAmount * 40) + 66, (rowAmount * 40) +
        // 66, Color.WHITE);

        scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
        backgroundPane.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        // theStage.setResizable(false);
        theStage.setScene(scene);
        theStage.show();
        level2 = new Level2(playerImage, wallImage, foodImage, diamondImage, player, wall, gameGrid, theStage, input, collision, wallCollision, foodWallCollision, players, foods, walls, diamonds);
        level2.startLevel2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);


    }

}
```

Level 1 class (I will split up the code further i'm just trying to get things to run at the moment)

```
  public abstract class Level1 {


     Pane backgroundPane;
    Pane playfieldLayer;
     Pane scoreLayer;

     Image playerImage;
      Image wallImage;
      Image foodImage;
     Image diamondImage;

     Player player;
      Wall wall;

     List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Diamonds> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();

     boolean collision;
     boolean wallCollision;
    boolean foodWallCollision;
     boolean won = false;

     GridPane gameGrid;
     Scene scene;
     Stage theStage;

     Input input;


        public Level1( Image playerImage, Image wallImage, 
                Image foodImage, Image diamondImage, Player player, Wall wall, GridPane gameGrid, Stage theStage, 
                Input input, boolean collision, boolean wallCollision, boolean foodWallCollision, List<Player> players,
                List<Food> foods,List<Wall> walls, List<Diamonds> diamonds)
       {



            this.playerImage = playerImage;
            this.wallImage = wallImage;
            this.foodImage = foodImage;
            this.diamondImage = diamondImage;
            this.player = player;
            this.wall = wall;
            this.gameGrid = gameGrid;
            this.theStage = theStage;
            this.input = input;
            this.collision = collision;
            this.wallCollision = wallCollision;
            this.foodWallCollision = foodWallCollision; 
            this.players = players;
            this.foods = foods;
            this.walls = walls;
            this.diamonds = diamonds; 

            //a billion getters and setters below.


        }
```

This is my level2 class which i want to be the first level that displays. My try catch statement is caught when the program runs so it is something to do with how i'm spawning the items onto my game field.

```
public class Level2 extends Level1{

    public Level2(Image playerImage, Image wallImage, 
            Image foodImage, Image diamondImage, Player player, Wall wall, GridPane gameGrid, Stage theStage, 
            Input input, boolean collision, boolean wallCollision, boolean foodWallCollision, List<Player> players,
            List<Food> foods,List<Wall> walls, List<Diamonds> diamonds){ 

       super(playerImage, wallImage, foodImage,diamondImage, player, 
               wall, gameGrid, theStage, input, collision, wallCollision, foodWallCollision, players, foods, walls, diamonds);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void startLevel2(){



        try {

            createPlayers();
            spawnFood();
            spawnWall();
            spawnDiamonds();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            System.out.println("You are missing the pictures for the spawn methods");
        }



        AnimationTimer gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // player input
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.processInput());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.processInput());

                // movement
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());
                // ((Player) players).stopInput();



                // check collisions


                // update sprites in scene
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());

            }

        };
        gameLoop.start();

    }



    private void createPlayers() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners();

        Image image = playerImage;

        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 1.0;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.8;

        Player player = new Player(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, 0, input);

        players.add(player);

    }

    private void spawnFood() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners();

        Image image = foodImage;

        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 2.0;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.4;


        //Food food1 = new Food(playfieldLayer, image, 150, 50, 0,0);

        Food food = new Food(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0,input);

        foods.add(food);
        //foods.add(food1);

    }



}
```

Comment: No idea, as I find this code way too complicated to comprehend. It is great that your ctor only inits fields, but we'll, the number of fields within that class is about 10 or 15 entries too long. So many fields mean that you are doing way too many things in that poor class. The essence of good OOP is to segregate different responsibilities into different classes!

Comment: I am very embarrassed by this code. Would it make more sense to split my collision methods into their own collision class?

Comment: Probably. But details would require to look at your whole code base. My recommendation: read about the single responsibility principle. And then create ONE new class PER responsibility. And look for some experienced folks to review your code base. Finally: don't feel embarrassed. Learning the true virtues of programming simply takes endless practicing.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaFX Application class cannot have an constructor with arguments, as an instance is created when calling `Application#launch()` (see [the life cycle of a JavaFX Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)). If you need your current constructor, make sure you have a no-argument constructor as well.

But maybe it is an good idea to separate your Application logic and your level logic, as it might become quit messy when adding even more levels in the future.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment. I've tried splitting up my code further (as shown above) but it now doesn't show anything.

Comment: You splited your code, solving the problem you described at first in the proces. So when other problems start to occur, please consider creating a new question, or put in the effort to solve the problem yourself. Right now your new question is out of the scope of this question, and waay to broad to be answered in a good way.

Comment: Okay doke well thankyou for the advice i tried up voting your answer but it doesn't seem to do much. I will make a new quesiton :)